# Deallocation for static class instance variable

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, memcached, spymemcached

This would be my first question, so please if I have not completed the question or left something out do let me know.

Background:
Well I have a Java based web-service and it is serving an iPhone app. It has connection to database and in order to improve the performance I have implemented caching using Memcached. The connector I use is spymemcached.

My question:
I have a static class which has a synchronous connection to the memcached server.
my reference is: http://sacharya.com/using-memcached-with-java/

But when I restart the memcached server or deploy another jar on tomcat I get this error:
**The web application appears to have started a thread name [some name] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.**

So, how do I deallocate the static class before I can restart or redeploy my application on tomcat?

--
Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the best answer is to not store the synchronous connection in a static variable or class.

Answer (score 1):

The static class is not the problem. That will be unloaded assuming that it is in a JAR in WEB-INF/lib. The problem is the thread. Whatever starts that thread needs to stop it. See this presentation for further details on Tomcat's memory leak prevention and detection:
http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Memory-Leaks-60mins.pdf

Answer (score -1):

That page implements a Singleton Pattern for MyCache class.
A singleton can't be destroyed.

Maybe you can define a ServletContextListener (or similar Listener in the app server) to stop the thread manually.

Comment: Wrong. A singleton can be destroyed if it is loaded by the web application's class loader. The GC is smart enough to handle this particular case when the web application class loader is stopped and is itself eligible for GC.

Comment: I am sure JVM can destroy it. My answer was related to the question "So, how do I deallocate the static class before I can restart or redeploy my application on tomcat?". Can't be destroyed at programming layer, that's the main problem of Singleton implementation.

Comment: So if I want to do it using code? How do I do that?
I know this is a silly question. Just curious.